# Occur weird characters when I use serial to communicate between my STM32F4 Discovery with my pc using PL2303

Tags: serial-port, uart, stm32f4discovery

I'm using HAL library to transmit and receive characters:

```
uint8_t c;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        if(HAL_UART_Receive(&huart5, &c, 1, 100) == HAL_OK)
        {
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart5, &c, 1, 100);
        }
  }
```

And after I install and load the code to my Discovery board, I use Hercules to start communicate and this hapen when I send a word or a letter:
[Occur weird characters when communicate using PL2303](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFL2T.png)

I have tried to find the solution but it didn't appear. I hope someone can help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You need to give more info. Try sending all 111111111111111 (x100) and in theory you should receive them all back. So see what you actually receive instead of 111111111. We need to establish relationship between input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me, Ilya. I solved this problem by setting the input frequency = 8MHz (I had set it up to 16Mhz so the serial can't read and send the data with the true frequency).

[Location of the input frequency in my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQQLe.png)